# Dynamic image upload and large image hover

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, yoxview

I have a page that is supposed to dynamically upload photos and then display them as a thumbnail. Basically, this consists of two files: `unit_edit.php` and `upload.php`. My upload works fine, therefore I won't bother posting it. It places the uploaded image in the proper folder as well as the thumbnail with its proper size.

My issue is that it does not display the image once it's uploaded - I have to refresh the page. Also, the hover to display the larger image does not work, either. I am using YoxView which is giving my errors in the console -  **Uncaught ReferenceError: options is not defined** I have to comment it out for the upload to work properly. I do not know how to define options. I tried following the [installation guide](http://www.yoxigen.com/yoxview/usage.aspx#installation) and it isn't working. Here is my relevant code:

Here is the div where the photos are created and placed

```
<div class="editunitimages">
        <form id="imageform" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action='upload.php?id=<?php print $_GET['id']; ?>' >
            Upload image <input type="file" name="photoimg" id="photoimg" />
        </form>

        <div id='preview'>
        </div>
        <div id="unit_images">
            <?php
                require_once('config/db.php');
                $con = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);
                $query = "SELECT id, image FROM images WHERE unit = ".$_GET['id']."";
                $result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
                echo '<div class="yoxview">';
                $i = 1;
                while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
                {
                    echo '<a href="unit_images/'.$row['image'].'"><img src="unit_images/thumbnails/'.$row['image'].'" alt="'.$i.'" title="image '.$i.'" /></a>';
                    $i++;
                }
                echo '</div>';
            ?>
        </div>
    </div>  <!-- end editunitimages -->
```

Here is the javascript

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() 
{ 
    //$("#thumbnails").yoxview([options]);
    $('#photoimg').live('change', function()    
    { 

        $("#preview").html('');
        $("#preview").html('<img src="images/loader.gif" alt="Uploading...."/>');
        $("#imageform").ajaxForm({
            target: '#preview'
        }).submit();
    });
}); 
</script>
```

Comment: Taking a quick look - it seems like you need to un-comment that line that is calling yoxview with the options. I believe since you never call yoxview it probably never sets to options object.

Comment: problem is I have no idea where it's defined or how to fix it.

Comment: Plus, the installation guide specifically says I don't need it if I don't want to. I just have to uncomment the last line of the `yoxview-nojquery.js` file

Comment: Ahh - sorry - I do not know much about this library. Since you are dynamically adding elements to the page have you tried listening for updates and then re-initing yoxview? This way it can attach to the new element (I would think it would handle this but it may not)

Comment: I actually got that part to work. My problem now is getting it to reload the div containing the images. I have to refresh the page and I want them to display automatically.